# ¿Como puedo corregir este error?

Tags: python

mi nombre es Victoria y hace poco que estoy entrando en el mundo de la programación. Tengo un proyecto de asistente virtual, no pretendo nada extraordinario simplemente quiero que sea un logro personal

Aquí la consulta:

Estoy utilizando una base de datos para registrar entradas y salidas no se si es un problema que tuve creando la tabla o algun problema en mi codigo

```
while palabra != 'adios': 
 palabra = escuchar() 
 print(palabra) 
 cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM proyecto") 
 nDatos = cursor.rowcount

 for fila in cursor:
   ide = fila[0]
   entrada = fila[1]
   salida = fila[2]
   similitud = SM(None,entrada,palabra).ratio
   numero = 0.7
   if similitud > numero:
    hablar(salida)
```

el error que sale es:

```
File "c:\Users\admin\OneDrive\Escritorio\Visual Studi Code\diana.py", line 54, in if similitud > 0.7: 
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'method' and 'float'
```

gracias por su tiempo,

saludos

Comment: lo que te devuelve `SM(None,entrada,palabra).ratio` no es un numero o no esta en el formato `int` o `float`

Answer (score 4):

La línea

```
similitud = SM(None,entrada,palabra).ratio
```

asigna a `similitud` un método (`ratio`), mientras que

```
similitud = SM(None,entrada,palabra).ratio()
```

asigna el valor del método retornado al llamar a dicho método.

Probablemente lo que buscas es lo último.